# How to theme one tab of a node

Tags: theming, routes

I have `hook_menu()` configured to show a tab for every node at `node/%node/summary`.  The callback for that page returns the correct content, but I'd like to add a bunch of HTML to the page.

I believe I need to create a `.tpl.php` file in my custom theme.  How do I know what to name the file and make sure that the template is used only on the correct pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 6, this would be:

```
 page-node-summary.tpl.php
```

More information on Drupal 6 template suggestions can be found at http://drupal.org/node/1089642

In Drupal 7, this would be:

```
 page--node--summary.tpl.php
```

More information on Drupal 7 template suggestions can be found at http://drupal.org/node/1089656

In either case, I'd grab the default page.tpl.php of your theme as a basis for it.

Comment: @htoip please tag your questions with 6 or 7 so people don't need to answer both methods...

Answer (score 0):

[The theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) allows you to point and click on any part of your page. It shows you all called and possible theme functions and template names.